# Is it possible to play with only one squad member?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I was just wondering if there was a way to edit Coalesced.bin to play with only one squad member in ME3 I thought it might be cool to go on a few missions with only Tali tagging along.

Comment: I doubt it, almost all missions have dialog for both squad members, no matter who they are

Comment: You could try to somehow freeze the squad member in place. Maybe its possible with cheats or something I don't know for sure but it might be possible

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. You are always required to take two team mates when going on a mission.

Comment: I might try downgrading to 1.4 and poking around with some cheats using the console, then. I played around with various settings in Coalesced.bin, but to no avail. Thanks guys!